# fftw c2c: missing symmetry in transformed real data

Tags: 2d, fft, fftw

recently I faced some problems concerning the use of fftw and it's c2c transformation (see: [3d c2c fft with fftw library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374656/3d-c2c-fft-with-fftw-library)). As I located my problems in the use of the fftw lib I created a new Question in order to discus this situation in a more concrete way.
Since I am doing a complex to complex transform with real data my transformed data in fourier space is supposed to be symmetric: F[n] = con(F[N-n])

Now I did some transformations with small blocks of test-data to check the transformed data for this symmetry. For 1D transform at every things worked as expected, but for higher dimensions I got real unexpected results.

I am using `fftwf_plan_dft_2d` to transform a 8x8 grayscale image into fourier space and the complex result is given by:

```
n 
0 real 7971 imag 0 
1 real -437.279 imag -802.151 
2 real -289 imag -566 
3 real -182.721 imag 15.8486 
4 real 31 imag 0 
5 real -182.721 imag -15.8486 
6 real -289 imag 566 
7 real -437.279 imag 802.151 
8 real -1499.79 imag -315.233 
9 real 182.693 imag -74.5563 
10 real 55.9239 imag -12.8234 
11 real -84.7868 imag -9.10052 
12 real -14.4264 imag 211.208 
13 real 289.698 imag 214.723 
14 real 452.659 imag -246.279 
15 real 1136.35 imag -763.85 
16 real 409 imag -134 
17 real -141.865 imag 42.6396 
18 real -33 imag 122 
19 real 129.075 imag -49.7868 
20 real 1 imag -150 
21 real 109.865 imag -84.6396 
22 real 95 imag -142 
23 real -841.075 imag -92.2132 
24 real -108.207 imag -89.2325 
25 real -127.213 imag 28.8995 
26 real -36.6589 imag -8.27922 
27 real -74.6934 imag 43.4437 
28 real 70.4264 imag 29.2082 
29 real -88.3545 imag -81.8499 
30 real -127.924 imag -190.823 
31 real 230.302 imag 8.7229 
32 real -53 imag 0 
33 real -73.1127 imag -22.8578 
34 real -85 imag -82 
35 real -10.8873 imag 51.1421 
36 real -65 imag 0 
37 real -10.8873 imag -51.1421 
38 real -85 imag 82 
39 real -73.1127 imag 22.8578 
40 real -108.207 imag 89.2325 
41 real 230.302 imag -8.7229 
42 real -127.924 imag 190.823 
43 real -88.3545 imag 81.8499 
44 real 70.4264 imag -29.2082 
45 real -74.6934 imag -43.4437 
46 real -36.6589 imag 8.27922 
47 real -127.213 imag -28.8995 
48 real 409 imag 134 
49 real -841.075 imag 92.2132 
50 real 95 imag 142 
51 real 109.865 imag 84.6396 
52 real 1 imag 150 
53 real 129.075 imag 49.7868 
54 real -33 imag -122 
55 real -141.865 imag -42.6396 
56 real -1499.79 imag 315.233 
57 real 1136.35 imag 763.85 
58 real 452.659 imag 246.279 
59 real 289.698 imag -214.723 
60 real -14.4264 imag -211.208 
61 real -84.7868 imag 9.10052 
62 real 55.9239 imag 12.8234 
63 real 182.693 imag 74.5563
```

Sorry for this long list of data, but it shows my problem.

For example for `F[3]=-182.721 + 15.8486i` I expected `F[64-3] = F[61] = -182.721 - 15.8486i`, but as you can see it is `-84.7868 + 9.10052i`. Instead the conjugate of `F[3]` is located at index 5. Same thing for other pairs.

If there is a system I cannot find it.

Here is the complete code:

```
QImage image("/Users/wolle/Desktop/wolf.png");
int w = image.width();
int h = image.height();
int size  = w * h;

cl_float *rawImage = imageToRaw(image); // converts a QImage into an rgb array [0..255]

fftwf_complex *complexImage = (fftwf_complex*) fftwf_malloc(sizeof(fftwf_complex) * size);
fftwf_complex *freqBuffer = (fftwf_complex*) fftwf_malloc(sizeof(fftwf_complex) * size);

// real data to complex data
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    complexImage[i][0] = (float)rawImage[i];
    complexImage[i][1] = 0.0f;
}

fftwf_plan forward = fftwf_plan_dft_2d(w, h, complexImage, freqBuffer, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

fftwf_execute(forward);

for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
    {
        int gid = y * w + x;
        qDebug() << gid  << "real" << freqBuffer[gid][0] << "imag" << freqBuffer[gid][1];
    }
}
```

I would appreciate some Help. :-D

Greetings

Wolf

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  You talk about a 16x16 image, but your data is only 64 items long.  Also, all of items in that list look like they have conjugate pairs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a 2D Fourier transform, it is still true that when x is real FFT(x) is conjugate-symmetric. But that's in two dimensions. So the (x,y) element at index 16*x+y should be the conjugate of the (16-x,16-y) element at index 16*(16-x mod 16)+(16-y mod 16), which when y isn't 0 is 272-16*x-y mod 256.

BUT I think that although you said 16x16 you actually meant 8x8. So (x,y) at 8*x+y is conjugate to (8-x,8-y) at 8*(8-x mod 8) + (8-y mod 8).

In particular, e.g., when x=0 the conjugate elements are y and 8-y -- including, for instance, 3 and 5, as you found.

(When x=0 or y=0, things like "8-y mod 8" above mean 0.)

Comment: Hey, thanks for this very nice explanation. This is the calculation I was looking for and your right it was really a 8x8 picture. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing: In case of `x = y = 0` I get the first Element `7917 + 0i` as far as I see it there is no counterpart.

Comment: Correct. The "DC term" is its own conjugate. Which reminds me: there was an error in what I wrote above: the x and y coordinates should individually be taken mod 8, rather than taking the whole thing mod 64. I've just fixed it.

Comment: When I make use of a filter, I have to apply it on both `f` and `con(f)`. As far as is see it I have to take care that the filter response is not applied a second time. Right?

Comment: I don't think I understand. Surely you apply the filter to the whole Fourier transform, once. Why would you be applying it separately to `f` and `con(f)`?

Comment: I think I made a mistake. `f` and `con(f)` have the same distance to the origin, so from the view of the filter (e.g. a low pass) they are equal, since `abs(x,x) = abs(-x,-x)`. So they are filtered equally and it is enough to just apply the filter response once.

Comment: Right. And you really shouldn't think of the filter as something you do to `f` and something else you do to `con(f)`; it's a single thing that happens to be symmetrical.

Comment: As far as I see it I it is beneficial to have odd-sized data since then I there is always a bin "in the middle".

Comment: There's always a bin in the middle, although the way Fourier coefficients are usually represented it's actually in the corner :-).

Comment: I thought though since I am shifting my coordinates this way: `shiftedN = n - N / 2` in order to achieve a point reflection between `f`and `con(f)`. But at the moment it produces strange results ;-))